# Not finding Raw floder in eclipse to work with android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am android beginer. I wanted to add audio file into my android application. In one of the tutorials i found that audio file need to be added to "RAW"folder but i am not finding such folder in my eclipse indigo version. somebody please tell me, did i delete it by mistake or have i not installed some file?

Comment: you should create it !!

Answer (score 1):

you should create it yourself, put it in the `res` folder and name it `raw` (lower case).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by two ways:

- Right click on `res` folder and create a folder named `raw`
- `Clear` / `Rebuild` your project

Or you can do it manually:

- Go throught the `workspace projects` go to your application / your package name / res / (Then you right click) Create Folder and named it `raw`.
- Restart the IDE and it will appear.